# Implementing keyboard (inputView) with UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am looking for the most direct way to make it so that when the user taps a `UITableViewCell`, a keyboard appears. I want to use a custom keyboard (`UIPickerView`) and I preferably would like to make the cell style `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`. I can't seem to find a very direct way of doing this. I have a navigation bar on top, and hoping to make the buttons on that change as well...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, to achieve this you're going to have to handle the custom animation of the UIPickerView sliding up and down. They keyboard is handled automatically by the controls that automatically need it (UITextField, UITextView, etc.).

So when your view loads you will want to create and configure your picker and then move its Y coordinate to `CGRectGetMaxY([[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]);`

Then in your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you will call a method that is responsible for animating your picker view into place. The only problem I foresee with this approach is allowing the user to dismiss this picker view in a way that makes sense as users are used to input views sliding only when they're needed (meaning that they appear when a view becomesFirstResponder and they disappear automatically when that view resignsFirstResponder status).

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve here and I would do it a bit differently. Instead of displaying a picker with options when you select a cell I would instead push a new tableViewController with your options laid out as cells. Then when the user makes a selection, you can set a checkmark and pop back to the original view.